# Is there a way to call function when App is running on background state?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I`m developing a app that need to run specific function continuously    when app is running on background state. And it should be stop when app is closed. Solution should be work for both IOS and Android platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ScheduledExecutorService :

```
ScheduledExecutorService execService
            =   Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
execService.scheduleAtFixedRate(()->{
            /*
                    you can call the repeated function here
                        */
        }, initialDelay, PERIOD, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

This will run even the app is minimized or in the background state.to stop this use

```
@override
public void onStopn()
{
      execService.shutdown()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AppState to check whether the user is in background or using the app. When the user is in background, use addListener() methods. This will work when the app is in background and stops when the app is closed. And most importantly its cross platform.

Please go through this [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html) for more information and examples.